# Guardar una tabla de una bd en un datatable y recorrer su informacion mientras tomo sus datos

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, poo

Mi problema es que tengo una tabla de la cual quiero tomar todos los campos y convertirlos en objeto lo que pasa es que solo tomo el primer dato de la consulta que quiero y no se como hacerle para recorrerlo mi codigo es el siguiente

Con este hago la consulta y segun yo tomo toda la tabla

```
 public static DataTable busqueda()
        {
            DataTable db = new DataTable();
            try
            {

                NpgsqlConnection connection;
                connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=root;Database=test;");
                connection.Open();
                string consulta = "SELECT boxnum, partnum, quantity, date, nivel, fila, profundidad FROM market ma INNER JOIN connection cn ON ma.boxnumm = cn.boxnum;";
                NpgsqlCommand com = new NpgsqlCommand(consulta, connection);
                NpgsqlDataAdapter adap = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(com);
                adap.Fill(db);
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por esto no funciona" + e.Message);
            }
            return db;


        }
```

luego lo en un timer intento iniciar el objeto, el timer es por si hay algun cambio en la base de datos pues estar re iniciando todos los objetos pero como lo tengo hasta ahorita solo toma el primer campo de mi consulta y luego crea objetos infinitos con el mismo dato, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = obtenerTabla.busqueda();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[0]; //guardo datos en variables
        partnum = Convert.ToString(row["partnum"]);
        cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(row["quantity"]);
        profundidad = Convert.ToInt32(row["profundidad"]);
        fila = Convert.ToInt32(row["fila"]);
        boxnum = Convert.ToInt32(row["boxnum"]);
        aux = Convert.ToDateTime(row["date"]);
        cajas.Add(new Caja(partnum,cantidad,profundidad,aux,fila,boxnum));
    }
    else
    {

    }
```

y pues no se como solucionarlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El objeto datatable debes recorrerlo como si fuera una matriz, hay que especificar el numero de fila y luego el numero o nombre de columna, debes usar un ciclo para recorrer todos los valores de la tabla.

```
for (int i=0; i< dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
//aca haces las operaciones con cada fila de la tabla ej:
partnum = dt.Rows[i]["partnum"].ToString();
}
```

Por otro lado no entiendo para que refrescar con un timer la tabla a menos que en tu operación estés eliminando registros

Comment: Si es que en realidad este es un tipo visualizador de datos y las tablas estan cambiando o pueden cambiar asi que actualizo todo y deja probar lo que me dices